# Vertical dots not horizontally centered

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I am trying to get the following equation, but I can't find a way to center the vertical dots. [image: The vertical dots are centered]

My current code is this:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
b(n_1) &= a_2 n_1{^2} + a_1n_1 + a_ 0\\
b(n_2) &= a_2 n_2{^2} + a_1n_2 + a_ 0\\
       & \vdots \\
b(n_L) &= a_2 n_L{^2} + a_1n_L + a_ 0,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Which gives this:
[image: Vertical dots not centered]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This alignment never vertically centers things, but left-aligns the signs after `&`. One thing you might do is to replace `\vdots` by `\makebox[12pt][c]{\vdots}`. Of course, if you are very picky, you may insist on precisely centered `\vdots`. Frankly, I would be much more concerned about the placement of the equation number. I'd use an ordinary `align` instead (which does not help on the issue with `\vdots` though) and only number the last equation. But that's just an opinion.

Comment: When I want to dots etc in such a situation I it manually using one or more of `\quad`, `\qquad` or `\hspace*{16mm}`. It might be a matter of taste but like you I would prefer one equation number that is centered on the system of equations here, rather than an equation at the end as suggested by marmot.

Comment: Marmot can you post this as an answer? :) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I did not read the question carefully. If you *really* want to use aligned, you could do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
b(n_1) &= a_2 n_1{^2} + a_1n_1 + a_ 0\\
b(n_2) &= a_2 n_2{^2} + a_1n_2 + a_ 0\\
       &\makebox[\widthof{$=a_2 n_2{^2} + a_1n_2 + a_ 0$}-\widthof{$b(n_2)$}][c]{\vdots} \\
b(n_L) &= a_2 n_L{^2} + a_1n_L + a_ 0,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I picked a random line and computed its approximate width with `calc` to center the `\vdots`. (Approximate because of the spacing around the `=`.) Let's see how well that works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
b(n_1) &= a_2 n_1{^2} + a_1n_1 + a_ 0\\
\tikzmark{1}b(n_2) &= a_2 n_2{^2} + a_1n_2 + a_ 0\tikzmark{2}\\
       &\makebox[\widthof{$=a_2 n_2{^2} + a_1n_2 + a_ 0$}-\widthof{$b(n_2)$}][c]{\vdots} \\
b(n_L) &= a_2 n_L{^2} + a_1n_L + a_ 0,
\end{aligned}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[red] (pic cs:1) -- (pic cs:2)
coordinate[midway](3);
\draw[red](3) -- ++(0,-1);}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Modulo the above-mentioned spacing around `=` that seems to work. I personally wouldn't use this in my own notes or papers, nor have I ever used aligned there because IMHO these vertically centered equation numbers insult my eyes. But of course this is only an opinion, so feel free to disagree. And I do not think my answer is the better option, when you wrote your comment you didn't even know it.... wait, do *you* have my [crystal ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOr3L.png)??? ;-)

Comment: But then the `\vdots` are horizontally centered only w.r.t. the RHS and not w.r.t. the full line width.

Comment: This isn't really centered sadly :'( I think it is because `\widthof{$=a_2 n_2{^2} + a_1n_2 + a_ 0$}` does not give the width of `b(n_1) &= a_2 n_1{^2} + a_1n_1 + a_ 0` (because of the &)

Comment: @DiogoTec Yes, sorry, I misread your question. I thought you wanted it to be centered w.r.t. the stuff on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility, with the `\vdotswithin` command from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eqlbl}
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    b(n_1) &= a_2 n_1{^2} & & + a_1n_1 + a_ 0\\
    b(n_2) &= a_2 n_2{^2} & & + a_1n_2 + a_ 0\\[-1.2ex]
 &\vdotswithin{ = } & & \vdotswithin{ + }\\[-1ex]
    b(n_L) &= a_2 n_L{^2} & & + a_1n_L + a_ 0,
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you need `eqparbox`?

Comment: @HenriMenke: It was  a first attempt – notsatisfying. I forgot to remove it from the code. Fixed now. Thanks for pointing the leftover!

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the fact that `aligned` is actually just `\halign` under the hood.  Then you can insert content spanning several columns using the Plain TeX macro `\multispan`.  You only need to know the number of columns for this to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    b(n_1) &= a_2 n_1{^2} + a_1n_1 + a_ 0\\
    b(n_2) &= a_2 n_2{^2} + a_1n_2 + a_ 0\\
    \multispan{2}\hfil$\vdots$\hfil\\
    b(n_L) &= a_2 n_L{^2} + a_1n_L + a_ 0,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I can offer another solution for `align`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    b(n_1) &= a_2 n_1{^2} + a_1n_1 + a_ 0\\
    b(n_2) &= a_2 n_2{^2} + a_1n_2 + a_ 0\\
    \noalign{\centering$\vdots$}
    b(n_L) &= a_2 n_L{^2} + a_1n_L + a_ 0,
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any way to number the whole system as one equation (as in my images), and that the number is centered vertically?

Comment: @DiogoTec You can place `\nonumber` on the lines you don't want to have numbered.  Vertically centered numbering is only possible with `aligned` but then the above trick does not work.

Comment: Alright, thank you! Given that I want the number centered, marmot answer seems a better option. Many thanks tho :)

Comment: @DiogoTec I added a second part to my answer.

Comment: @DiogoTec I have found another solution which does not require you to know the width of the alignment.